# Download vega-lite chart rendered as svg in Observablehq

Tags: vega-lite, observablehq

I'm learning Observablehq and Vega Lite. I created this observable : https://observablehq.com/@mavromatika/untitled

I don't understand why The interface won't let me download the chart, neither as SVG nor as PNG. I know it should work because both downloads are possible on the charts in the example page : https://observablehq.com/@vega/vega-lite-api (SVG only when properly rendered).

There's got to be something obvious that's escaping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's a bug, if you change the width to >= 500px the UI buttons to save SVG/PNG appears. I'll report it on the forum

```
something = {
    const plot = vl.markBar()
                  .data(data)
                  .encode(
                    vl.x().fieldN("annee"),
                    vl.y().fieldQ("valeur"),
                    vl.color().fieldN("emission")
                  )
                  .width(500)
                  .height(500)
                  .autosize({type: 'fit-x', contains: 'padding'})

      return plot.render({renderer: 'svg'});
}
```

Comment: Indeed, Mike Bostock informed about this on the Observable forum. One can also reduce the browser's window's width and the download item in the menu magically appears.

Comment: interesting, it works just changing the browser width, it's definitely a bug